# Cassandra cql-function to return dayOfYear

Tags: cassandra, cql

Does Cassandra have a cql-function to return the dayOfYear from now()?
So that I can use it to populate my column automatically?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO modified_records (timeslot, updatedtime, recordid)
VALUES (dayOfYear(now()), toTimestamp(now()), 789)
```

I went through datastax docs and some Google, but could not find any such thing.
Hence asking any expert user for a not-so-well-documented option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by `dayOfYear()` you are referring to the [mysql function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofyear), I don't believe such a capability currently exists using just cql.

However, you could make timeslot a `date`-typed column, `toDate()` ([reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html)) would convert a `now()`-generated `timeuuid` into a `date`, i.e.:

```
cqlsh:simple> INSERT INTO modified_records (timeslot, updatedtime, recordid) VALUES (toDate(now()), toTimestamp(now()), 789);
cqlsh:simple> select * from modified_records;

 recordid | timeslot   | updatedtime
----------+------------+--------------------------
      789 | 2017-02-28 | 2017-02-28 00:53:46+0000
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Any chance there is something to include hour too in the `timeslot` column above?

Comment: glad that worked :).  As far as storing the current hour, not that I am aware of.  At the point it might be better to do that in the client (using a driver) to create a date from current time and then change the precision to hours.